# PostgreSQLのソートで英字昇順、数字昇順で表示

Tags: postgresql

PostgreSQL バージョン 9.3 で「英字の昇順」「数字の昇順」とソートをかけたいのですが、
方法はありますでしょうか。

0001
0003
0010
a001
d001
k001
i001
z001

↓ ORDER BYをすると以下にソートしたいのですが、方法はありますでしょうか。

a001
d001
i001
k001
z001
0001
0003
0010

Answer (score 1):

```
create table mytable (
  mycolumn char(4)
);

insert into mytable(mycolumn) values 
('0001'), ('0003'), ('0010'), ('a001'), ('d001'), ('k001'), ('i001'), ('z001');
```

1文字目が数字の場合は英字の場合よりソート順を下げる、ということであれば次のような`order by`を設定するというのはどうでしょうか。

```sql
select * from mytable
order by case when mycolumn ~'^\d' then 2 else 1 end, mycolumn;
```

結果:

```
 mycolumn 
----------
 a001
 d001
 i001
 k001
 z001
 0001
 0003
 0010
(8 rows)
```

Comment: 返信遅れてすみません。
確認できました。ありがとうございます。